# Perl: Compose a regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Problem creating a Regular Expression.

I have a big list that looks like this:

```
4912345671;Test1;489
4912345686;Test2;953
4912345699;Test3;89
```

Now Lets say thats an array of the list that is splitted so its like

```
$line[0] = Number
$line[1] = Text
$line[2] = Length
```

Now the Problem is I have another List which looks like this:

```
49123456-0;0-99;Company 1;Street;Number 1;Post Code;City
```

No what I want to do is look in the first list if it starts with the Number until - so in this case: 49123456

Now if it start with that number it should check if the next Numbers are between the Area 0-99 (in this case) so all numbers from: 49123456-0 until 99 (excluding 01 - 09):

```
491234560
4912345610
4912345611
...
4912345620
4912345621
and so on...
```

What also important is that it doesent start from 01. If the numbers are in the area 0 - 99

It includes the 0 but not 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09 so it starts from 10 and then so on until 99. Same thing if its 0 - 999 then it includes the 0 but starts from 100.

What I want to do is have a List later on which looks like the first one and includes a column with the Phone Area Number so in this case it would look like this:

```
4912345671;Test1;489;49123456
4912345686;Test2;953;49123456
4912345699;Test3;89;49123456
```

I hope somebody can help me. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about *specific programming problems*, it is not a place to get code written for you. If you do you best and reach a hurdle you cannot overcome then show your code here and we will help you fix it.

Comment: Is this not just repeating the first column with the last two digits removed? What happens if `4912345605` appears (i.e. ending with `01` to `09`)

Comment: @Borodin This will not happen but if it happens it should be ignored. I am not asking for code I am asking for a regular expression, because I am not so good in writing them. I mean it is simple to write easy ones but for such a thing I just dont know how to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this. Use `substr` to remove the last two characters of a string like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /;/;
  push @fields, $fields[0];
  substr $fields[-1], -2, 2, '';
  print join(';', @fields), "\n";
}

__DATA__
4912345671;Test1;489
4912345686;Test2;953
4912345699;Test3;89
```

**output**

```
4912345671;Test1;489;49123456
4912345686;Test2;953;49123456
4912345699;Test3;89;49123456
```

Comment: I also know how to remove the last two characters the Problem is that I have to check if the number is in the area from the second column

Comment: Why do you need to do any checking? Just trim everything like I have shown